# Using Bibtex with Texworks, undefined control sequence in bbl file

Tags: bibtex

So I followed the advice given on a previous forum:

```
Compile with PdfLatex to get the .aux file
Compile with Bibtex to get the .bbl file
Compile with Pdflatex to incorporate the .bbl file
```

But when I did this last step I had an error saying "Undefined control sequence" in the `.bbl` file. The only thing I could come up with is that there is some formatting issue when reading the `.bib` file. I do not know how to overcome this though.

If someone has the solution, please could you help. I am using TexWorks (Texlive 2016)

**EDIT**
Here is my file :

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{natbib}

\captionsetup{margin=12pt,font=small,labelfont=bf}
\setlength{\absleftindent}{30mm}
\setlength{\absrightindent}{30mm}
\newcommand{\figref}[1]{\figurename~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\eqnref}[1]{Equation ~\ref{#1}} \newcommand{\secref}[1]{Section~\ref{#1}}

\begin{document}
    ...
    \cite{2010SPIE.7740E..22M}

    \bibliography{2016SAM_survey}{}
    \bibliographystyle{aa.bst}
\end{document}
```

And the error I get it this after compiling with Bibtex and then PdfLatex again:

```
(./mphys background report2.bbl ! Undefined control sequence. l.6 ...lov}, A., \& {Feldt}, M. 2010, in \procspie , Vol. ?
```

My `.bbl` file looks like this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1} \expandafter\ifx\csname     natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi

\bibitem[{{Mller-Nilsson} {et~al.}(2010){Mller-Nilsson}, {Pavlov}, \& {Feldt}}]{2010SPIE.7740E..22M} {Mller-Nilsson}, O., {Pavlov}, A., \& {Feldt}, M. 2010, in \procspie, Vol. 7740, Software and Cyberinfrastructure for Astronomy, 774022
\end{thebibliography}
```

And my Bib file looks like this:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{2010SPIE.7740E..22M,
   author = {{Mller-Nilsson}, O. and {Pavlov}, A. and {Feldt}, M.},
    title = "{SPHERE data reduction software: first insights into data reduction software development for next-generation instruments}",
booktitle = {Software and Cyberinfrastructure for Astronomy},
     year = 2010,
   series = {\procspie},
   volume = 7740,
    month = jul,
      eid = {774022},
    pages = {774022},
      doi = {10.1117/12.857989},
   adsurl = {http://cdsads.u-strasbg.fr/abs/2010SPIE.7740E..22M},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

Thanks,
Toni

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  without seeing the full error message and the content that triggered it (preferably embedded in a small compilable example that demonstrates the problem), it's impossible to provide any useful answer.

Comment: Please add the bib entry to your question! the bbl part is not enoupg information.  Do you have command `\procspie` in your bib file? If yes you have to define it ...

Comment: The braces in the `.bib` file are wrong: it should be `author={Mller-Nilsson, O. and Pavlov, A. and Feldt, M.}` and `title={{SPHERE} data reduction...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I do not have your bibliography style `aa.bst` I simply used `plainnat`.

Please see that command `\bibliographystyle{aa}` needs no extention `.bst`.

To get rid of the error you get you have to define the used command `\procspie` in your code like

```
\newcommand{\procspie}{Proceedings of the SPIE} % <=====================
```

Change `Proceedings of the SPIE` to your needs ...

The following MWE compiles without error(s):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@INPROCEEDINGS{2010SPIE.7740E..22M,
   author = {{Mller-Nilsson}, O. and {Pavlov}, A. and {Feldt}, M.},
    title = "{SPHERE data reduction software: first insights into data reduction software development for next-generation instruments}",
booktitle = {Software and Cyberinfrastructure for Astronomy},
     year = 2010,
   series = {\procspie},
   volume = 7740,
    month = jul,
      eid = {774022},
    pages = {774022},
      doi = {10.1117/12.857989},
   adsurl = {http://cdsads.u-strasbg.fr/abs/2010SPIE.7740E..22M},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{natbib}

\captionsetup{margin=12pt,font=small,labelfont=bf}
\setlength{\absleftindent}{30mm}
\setlength{\absrightindent}{30mm}
\newcommand{\figref}[1]{\figurename~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\eqnref}[1]{Equation ~\ref{#1}} \newcommand{\secref}[1]{Section~\ref{#1}}

\newcommand{\procspie}{Proceedings of the SPIE} % <=====================


\begin{document}
\cite{2010SPIE.7740E..22M}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % <================================= aa, without .bst
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

to

[image: resulting pdf]